# Modify firebase rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using this firebase rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /classes/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if isSignedIn();
    }

    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == userId || isSignedIn() && hasPermission();
    }
  }

  function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth.uid != null;
  }

  function hasPermission() {
    return request.auth.uid in resource.data.ruleList;
  }
}
```

The `rulesList` `contains` my user_uuid. If a user wants to manage his own documents it works. There the pat would be for example: `/users/32T9lJ5nSEZrhLgxul4goBcscqk2/...data`. But admins should read the data of other users too. And exactly that does not work. When the `ruleList` contains a user_uuid he should be able to read all data of every user. What I am doing wrong?
The following code gets the user user_uuids from a collection called "classes" and searches after the name of each user:

```
db.collection("classes").doc(klasse).get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      const data = doc.data();
      const members = data.members;

      members.reduce((chain, el) => {
        return chain
        .then(() => db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("user_data").doc("u").get())
        .then(doc => {
          const data = doc.data();
          var member_name = data.name;
        })
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(console.log("finished"));
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

It returns a warning caused by insufficient permission.
~filip

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that isn't working the way you expect with these rules.  The code must always match with rules, and looking at one or the other isn't enough information.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you please have a look at my edit. :) I updated it

Comment: Can you show the specific query that's failing, without including any variables?  What you have now depends on us knowing all the values of variables in play, as well as the contents of your database.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example